# Change Marker Style/Color in Python StatsModels Probplot

Tags: python, statsmodels

I would like to change the marker size (or line width) for PP plots that are made by StatsModels. See [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/graphics.html) the associated documentation and [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html#statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot) for an example of QQ plots - these are similar.

The line in the graph looks very fat now -- too fat! See pic:

[image: PP plot from statsmodels]

which was generated using the code below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
probplot = smp.ProbPlot(levels.mv15, fit=True)
res=probplot.ppplot(ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Market Values")
plt.show()
```

I tried the answer for a similar question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463189/change-marker-style-color-in-python-probplot)), however that works with SciPy, not with StatsModels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was simple:

```
res=probplot.ppplot(ax=ax5, markersize=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you making a QQ plot, it's easy to do with sm.qqplot, which allows you to pass kwargs, e.g.

```
sm.qqplot(res, line='s', **{'markersize':1, 'alpha':0.9})
```