# QQ plots with scipy and matplolib. I can neither plot a legend nor change plot styles

Tags: python, matplotlib

> I am drawing these 2 QQ plots with scipy and then Matplolib. I can neither plot a legend (please see error, "no handles with labels found") nor make changes to the style or colors of line/plo. I suspect because I cannot grab the object.

Can you help fix this?

- adding legend
- change plot color let's say to purple
- change line style to "- -"
  Thank you!

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)

ax1 =plt.subplot(121)
ax2=plt.subplot(122)
    
stats.probplot(arr1, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax1)   
ax1.set_title("Probability Plot",fontsize=14)
ax1.set_ylabel("Sample Quantiles",fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlabel("Theoretical Quantiles",fontsize=12)    

stats.probplot(arr2, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax2)   
ax2.set_title("Probability Plot",fontsize=14)
ax2.set_ylabel("Sample Quantiles",fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xlabel("Theoretical Quantiles",fontsize=12)
ax2.legend()   
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is `stats`? statsmodels? Imports are essential parts of the code. Ah, I see. [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html#scipy.stats.probplot)

Answer (score 2):

For the legend you can pass the string into `ax2.legend()`
ie. `ax2.legend('string')`

Regarding colors and style you can try `ax.get_lines()`, checkout the doc for [lineobject](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D/) and another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463189/change-marker-style-color-in-python-probplot/)